# Repeating background color pattern through jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, json

I'm trying to think of a way to repeat background color patterns on my li elements through jquery. Right now, I'm using classes for each specific background color. I know there must be an easier way to have the same pattern repeat down the list through jquery. Like every fifth li should be yellow, every second blue, and so on. Ultimately, the li's will be added dynamically from external data hence the reason i need it to be more automated.

Here is a link to my JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nYJj/2/

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

Big D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With jQuery:**

```
$('ul li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('liClass' + i%5);
});
```

For this you must change your `li` class names to `liClass0` .. `liClassN`.

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nYJj/25/)

Comment: Great solution, thanks a million! nth-child would work great, but i have to support IE

Comment: You can safely combine the two approaches so it works in modern browsers even if JS is disabled. (Use `li:nth-child(5n+1), .liClass0` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If CSS3 is an option, you can do the following:

```
ul li:nth-child(5n+1){
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4nYJj/5/

Answer (score 0):

after theyre done loading you could just run an each function on them that add the classes based on a variable that you start at 1 and increment on each loop run and just reset it to 1 after it reaches 5.

Something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 1;
$('#dyno_ul li').each(function(){
if(i == 1){$(this).addClass('first');i++;}
....
if(i == 5){$(this).addClass('fifth');i = 1;}

});});
```

Comment: ahh i'll have to look that up.  LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's quite possible to do so with jquery, I think that might be an overkill. CSS is definitely a better way to handle this kind of work. CSS3 gives you pseudo-classes like nth-child which can be put to good use to get the desired result without much effort.

```
ul li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+2) {
    background-color: blue;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+3) {
    background-color: purple;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+4) {
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Check it out at - http://jsfiddle.net/dhruvasagar/hRHp3/

Comment: This is a great solution, the only problem is that i need to support IE7+, I don't believe nth-child is supported in IE.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery:

```
var i = 1;
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('alt' + i);
    i = (i == 5) ? 1 : i + 1;
});
```

CSS:

```
.alt1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.alt2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.alt3 {
    background-color: purple;
}

.alt4 {
    background-color: red;
}

.alt5 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/VbVvZ/

Answer (score 0):

with the css3-nth selector you can simple select those without js

```
ul li:nth-child(5n+1){
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+2){
    background-color: blue;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+3){
    background-color: purple;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+4){
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+5){
    background-color: green;
}
```

---

with js you can do this with a modulo

```
  $('li').each(function(){
      if (c % 1 == 0) {  cls = 'first';  }
      if (c % 2 == 0) {  cls = 'second';  }    
      if (c % 3 == 0) {  cls = 'third';  }
      if (c % 4 == 0) {  cls = 'fourth';  }
      if (c % 5 == 0) {  cls = 'fifth';  }

      $(this).attr('class',cls);
      if (++c >= 5) {
        c = 0;
      };
  });
```